LWC Outlook pane component using the Lightning__Inbox target
I have two questions regarding the lack of documentation on building email pane components for Salesforce to support Outlook and Gmail.

How can you retrieve the HTML body of the email instead of just the text body? Currently, the messageBody parameter in your component only provides the text version of the email.

When switching between emails in Outlook Web or Gmail, how can you update your state based on the new data in the Salesforce plugin? The built-in components change their state, but my component isn't aware of this change by default. Is there a specific event or message subscription to listen for these updates?


